# How do i sanitize the query below?

Tags: php, mysql

can someone teach me how to sanitize the query ? Should i sanitize $first_word too ?

```
$question_text = sanitize($_POST['question_text']);

list($first_word) = explode(' ', $question_text);

$qStuff=mysql_query("SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t, taxonomy_domain d WHERE c.category_id = t.category_id AND t.domain_id = d.domain_id AND c.field_name = '$first_word'");
```

Comment: What does "sanitize" mean/do in this case?

Comment: sanitize to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 2):

use PDO and parameter binding like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (?)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$sth->execute(array($value));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using `mysql_*` function, you must use [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to escape your string data :

```
$first_word_escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($first_word);
$qStuff=mysql_query("SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t, taxonomy_domain d 
     WHERE c.category_id = t.category_id 
           AND t.domain_id = d.domain_id 
           AND c.field_name = '$first_word_escaped'");
```

Note : as said in the [Overview of the mysqli extension][2] *(quoting)* :

> **What is PHP's MySQL Extension?**
>
> This is the original extension
> designed to allow you to develop PHP
> applications that interact with a
> MySQL database.
> The mysql extension
> provides a procedural interface and is
> intended for use only with MySQL
> versions older than 4.1.3.
> This
> extension can be used with versions of
> MySQL 4.1.3 or newer, but not all of
> the latest MySQL server features will
> be available.
>
> **Note:** If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly
> recommended that you use the
> **mysqli** extension instead.

Another solution would be to stop using the `mysql_*` familly of functions, and switch to eiter [**mysqli**][3] or [**PDO**][4], using Prepared Statements -- which are one of the *new features* that are not supported by `mysql_*` :

- [**`mysqli::prepare`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php),
- [**`PDO::prepare`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

With those, you would have to escape your data : it would be done automatically when binding their values.

Answer (score 0):

"Sanitizing" is not necessarily the same as "SQL escaping". To SQL escape values for MySQL, use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the value you're going to put into the query:

```
$first_word = current(explode(' ', $_POST['question_text']));

// sanitize $first_word here if you want to to remove certain things

mysql_query("SELECT … '" . mysql_real_escape_string($first_word) . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a preg_match statement to limit character types. I also suggest using PHP PDO and prepared SQL statements. I'm on mobile or I would post links.

Answer (score 0):

Use modern database functionality like PDO, and make use of paramterised queries.